# Issue with apt-maven-plugin and com.mysema.query.apt.roo.RooAnnotationProcessor

Tags: maven, querydsl

I am **unable to generate Q classes** from my `@RooJpaEntity` annotated classes.

Here is my plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution> 
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory> 
                        <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.roo.RooAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        <options>
                            <querydsl.packageSuffix>.querydsl</querydsl.packageSuffix>
                        </options>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Here is what I get from a `mvn -X generate-sources`:

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:1.0.8:process' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (s) options = {querydsl.packageSuffix=.querydsl}
[DEBUG]   (s) outputDirectory = /home/julien/Documents/donnees/projets/site-garde-enfants/java/bignibou/src/main/java
[DEBUG]   (s) pluginArtifacts = [com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:1.0.8:, org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-build-api:jar:0.0.7:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.8:compile, backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11:compile, junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:compile]
[DEBUG]   (s) processor = com.mysema.query.apt.roo.RooAnnotationProcessor
[DEBUG]   (s) project = MavenProject: com.bignibou:bignibou:0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT @ /home/julien/Documents/donnees/projets/site-garde-enfants/java/bignibou/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (s) sourceEncoding = UTF-8
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Using build context: org.sonatype.plexus.build.incremental.DefaultBuildContext@383035a1
[DEBUG] There is no sources to generatate querydsl classes from (skipping)
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Which Querydsl version are you using? Why do you use src/main/java as the outputDirectory, something under target is recommeded and do you have RooJpaEntity on your compile classpath?

Comment: Hi Timo! I use version 3.1.0. What do you mean by _do you have RooJpaEntity on your compile classpath_?

Comment: I've always used src/main/java as the outputDirectory and it used to work. I will change to something under target if it is really needed.

Comment: target/generated-sources/java is a recommended target folder, I meant a compile scope dependency which includes the RooJpaEntity. Please open a ticket at GitHub with a minimal example project (pom + RooJpaEntity annotated entity) if the problem doesn't go away.

Comment: I'll fix that weird typo in the logging

Comment: Can you provide a sample snippet for the compile scope dependency? Do you mean a dependency to the plugin?

Comment: No, I mean a dependency to Spring Roo or more specifically to the artifact that contains the RooJpaEntity annotation.

Comment: OK. Well yes the jar is on the classpath, otherwise the project would not compile.

Comment: Then file a bug https://github.com/mysema/querydsl/issues

Comment: I am in the process of doing so with a sample app.

Comment: Timo: I have the sample project ready. It is [here](https://github.com/balteo/querydsl/tree/master/roo-querydsl-issue.balteo). Let me know if I can help further.