# how to add option for maven apt plugin?

Tags: java, maven

as titled.

```xml
<options>
    <option>field=D:\com.googlecode\target\generated-sources\apt</option>
</options>
```

I use this but print:

```
-Afield=D:\com.googlecode\target\generated-sources\apt=null
```

it is `null`?

what's the right format?

Comment: should be null without setting any value

Comment: how to set ? I doesn't know the right foramt to write 'option'?

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```xml
<options>
    <field>D:\com.googlecode\target\generated-sources\apt</field> 
</options>
```

Comment: @jiafu In the wrong plugin sorry, as in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856855/issue-with-apt-maven-plugin-and-com-mysema-query-apt-roo-rooannotationprocessor). I looked into the source of yours and it should work the way you are using it.